# I want to fetch value from scenarios and set value in QueryParam

Tags: gatling

I want to fetch a value from the scenario and set value in queryParam. My code is..

```
val scen1 = scenario("Home page").repeat(1) {
 exec(session => session
   .set("queryEnc", URLEncoder.encode(updateQueueItemCreatedTime(fileContents).toString.replace(" ", "%20"), "UTF-8"))
   .set("authroization", AwsSigner(AwsCredentialsProviderWithSession, region, Service, () => LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).getSignedHeaders(Uri, PostMethod, EmptyQueryParams ++ Map("Action" -> "SendMessage", "MessageBody" ->"${queryEnc}"), headers, emptyPayload)("Authorization"))
 )
 .exec(
    http("Custom headers")
     .get(queueUrl + "?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=" + "${queryEnc}")
     .header("Authorization", "${authroization}")
   )
}
```

When I fetch value in `.get` method using `"${queryEnc}"` this. Then value pass as which I want. But when I fetch the value in  `Map("Action" -> "SendMessage", "MessageBody" ->"${queryEnc}")` then it get same string as `"${queryEnc}"`, not get value from session.

How will I pass the value in MessageBody?

Answer (score 0):

When you're inside a session function as you are when calling session.set, you can't use the gatling expression language "${var}" as a shorthand for getting a session value.

Instead you have to use the session api directly.

so instead of

```
.set("authroization", ... EmptyQueryParams ++ Map("Action" -> "SendMessage", "MessageBody" ->"${queryEnc}"), headers, emptyPayload)("Authorization"))
```

you need

```
.set("authroization", ... EmptyQueryParams ++ Map("Action" -> "SendMessage", "MessageBody" -> session("queryEnc").as[String], headers, emptyPayload)("Authorization"))
```

Comment: After applying this code. it gives an error when I run it. The error is ' failed to execute: No attribute named 'queryEnc' is defined'